# SQL joining multiple tables with count

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Description of tables:

```
Table Members:
  id
  name
  status

Table Memberships:
  id
  date_start
  date_end
  date_added
  cost
  member_id
  status
  membership_type

Table Things:
  id
  name
  quantity
  member_id
  status
```

With following query i wanted to get table/view that would display me "MEMBERSHIP" for each "MEMBER" that will have sum of "THINGS" in the last column for each "MEMBER".

Logic is this: "MEMBERS" is one member per record, Each "MEMBER" can have multiple "MEMBERSHIPS" and each "MEMBER" can have multiple "THINGS" records.

However, following query returns me sum of quantity of things multiplied with the number of memberships that each user have.

```
  select
  memberships.id,
  memberships.member_id,
  members.name,
  members.status,
  memberships.membership_type,
  memberships.date_start,
  memberships.date_end,
  memberships.date_added,
  memberships.cost,
  memberships.status
  sum(things.quantity) as quantity
  from memberships
  right join members on memberships.member_id = members.id
  right join things on things.member_id = members.id
  where NOW() between memberships.date_start and memberships.date_end
  and memberships.status = 1
  and things.status = 1
  and members.status = 1
  group by members.id, memberships.member_id
```

Comment: Instead of doing right join with things, you could have an inner table with sum(things.quantity) and things.member_id which is grouped by things.member_id

Comment: @ChetterHummin i know but this is so simple project, i don't want to make things more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate each records on separate subquery in order for you to achieve correct results. If you join the tables and calculate it directly, you will have invalid result because `members` can have multiple records on `membership` table as well as multiple `things` on `Things` table.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.totalMembership, 0) totalMembership,
        COALESCE(c.TotalThings, 0) TotalThings
FROM    Members a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  member_id, COUNT(*) totalMembership
            FROM    Memberships 
            GROUP   BY member_ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.member_ID
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  member_ID, SUM(quantity) TotalThings
            FROM    Things
            GROUP   BY member_ID
        ) c ON a.ID = c.member_ID
```

Comment: Although i exactly needed that membership table is the "central one", i hope this is ok. I'm going to try it.

Comment: additionally, you need to add conditions inside the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

As i was experimenting, i find out another work around with no need for sub queries and it's 100% useful for similar scenarios.

I just added a column in select that is being calculated like this:

```
(sum(things.quantity) DIV count(distinct memberships.id)) as quantity
```

And, voilà, it works :)